# Is it possible to log the output of the Scala REPL?

Tags: scala, logging, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a way to log the output of the Scala REPL in a file ?

Comment: Did you have a look at .scala_history? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561719/is-there-a-quick-way-to-show-the-code-of-a-method-declared-in-the-scala-console

Comment: @mhs Thank you, but .scala_history only saves the commands I typed, not the REPL output as a whole.

Comment: My bad, I missed that part of your question.

Comment: how about just hitting "save" in your terminal window?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494014/scala-interactive-interpreter-repl-how-to-redirect-the-output-to-a-text-file it is not possible with 2.9. Give it a try in 2.10.

Comment: If your are using Unix-like system (including MacOS), I think `scala | tee log` is the simplest method. It will catch all input and output of your scala REPL to the file named `log`.

Answer (score 2):

You could import java.util.PrintWriter and have some code like this:

```
val out = new PrintWriter("out.txt")
out.println("output string")
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: it's java.io.PrintWriter